# Django restframework import data from another table?

Tags: python, mysql, django, django-queryset

I'm using Django rest framework with MySQL.

Let me explain my two tables.

[article]
- articleNo(Primary key)
- content

[comment]
- articleNo(FK to article)
- userkey
- comment

I want to import comment data to artice table.

```
class articleDetailSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    userkey = userSerializer(read_only=True)
    likeCount = serializers.IntegerField(source='like_set.count', read_only=True)
    commentCount = serializers.IntegerField(source='comment_set.count', read_only=True)
    comment = serializers.PrimaryKeyRelatedField(many=True, read_only=True)

    class Meta:
        model = article
        fields = ('articleNo', 'userkey', 'content', 'likeCount', 'commentCount', 'comment')

class commentSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
         model = comment
         fields = ('articleNo', 'content', 'userkey')
```

When I visit /article, Current output is:

```
{
    "articleNo": 26,
    "userkey": {
        "userkey": "121212",
        "username": "Da"
    },
    "content": "test",
    "likeCount": 3,
    "comment": [
        1,
        2,
        3
    ]
},
```

What I would like instead as output is something like:

```
{
    "articleNo": 26,
    "userkey": {
        "userkey": "121212",
        "username": "Da"
    },
    "content": "test",
    "likeCount": 3,
    "comment": [
        {
            articleNo: 26,
            userkey: "12345",
            content: "first comment"
        },
        {
            articleNo: 26,
            userkey: "23456",
            content: "second comment"
        },
        {
            articleNo: 26,
            userkey: "33333",
            content: "third comment"
        },
    ]
},
```

Can it be implemented with Rest framework?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to change type of `comment` field from `PrimaryKeyField` to `commentSerializer` inside `articleDetailSerializer`:

```
class articleDetailSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    ...
    comment = commentSerializer(many=True, read_only=True)

    class Meta:
        model = article
        fields = ('articleNo', 'userkey', 'content', 'likeCount', 'commentCount', 'comment')
```

See details [here](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/relations/#nested-relationships).

Comment: I already do this but it throws error.

    comment = commentSerializer(many=True, read_only=True)
NameError: name 'commentSerializer' is not defined

Comment: @Hide declare `commentSerializer` before `articleDetailSerializer`. Just made it be above in your code.

Comment: I forgor it. Thanks!

Comment: It occurs another issue. I fixed code, seems everything will be fine. But commentCount Column is disappered. What should I do?

Comment: @Hide Not sure but probably serializermethodfield will help you. Read more here http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/fields/#serializermethodfield